# Creating a angular2 service that displays a processing overlay

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, observable

I am trying to create a reusable component that serves as a processing overlay when making asynchronous calls across my site. I have a service in place but the OverlayComponent doesn't seem to get invoked when `showOverlay` is invoked:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MainComponent } from './app.mysite.component';
import { OverlayComponent } from './app.mysite.overlay.component';
import { TrackerComponent } from './pages/tracker/mysite.tracker.component';

import { OverlayService } from "./overlay.service";

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpModule ],
    declarations: [
                    MainComponent,
                    OverlayComponent,
                    NavbarComponent,
                    TrackerComponent,
                  ],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}, OverlayService],
    bootstrap:    [ MainComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**TrackerComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { OverlayService } from '../../overlay.service.js';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'tracker-component',
    templateUrl: '/public/app/templates/pages/tracker/mysite.tracker.component.html',
    providers: [ OverlayService]
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private http: Http, private overlayService: OverlayService) {

    }
    ngOnInit(): void {


        this.overlayService.showOverlay('Processing...'); //This kicks everything off but doesn't show the alert or overlay
        this.overlayService.test(); //does exactly what i'd expect
    }
}
```

**overlay.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

export class OverlayService {
    private message: string;
    private subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

    showOverlay(msg: string) : void { //When this gets invoked, shouldn't it be invoking a change to this.subject and therefore invoking getMessage()
        this.message = msg;
        this.subject.next(msg);
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

    test() {
        return 'test good'; //if I call this function, it works
    }

}
```

**app.mysite.overlay.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OverlayService } from './overlay.service';

@Component({

    selector: 'overlay-component',
    templateUrl: '/public/app/templates/mysite.overlay.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['public/app/scss/overlay.css'],
    providers: [OverlayService]
})

export class OverlayComponent implements OnInit {
    private processingMessage: string;
    constructor(private overlayService: OverlayService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.overlayService.getMessage().subscribe((message: string) => { //since i'm subscribed to this, i'm expecting this to get called. It doesn't
            this.processingMessage = message;
            alert(this.processingMessage); //never gets hit
            $('.overlay-component-container').show(); // never gets hit
        },
        error => {
            alert('error');
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of Angular2 are you using?

Comment: It should be what's currently released. Everything in my package.json is 2.1.1 ( i want to say beta 17)

Comment: TrackerComponent is importing with `import { OverlayService } from '../../overlay.service.js';` try removing the ".js" extension

Comment: When I change that path, it results in the following:

Comment: public/app/ts/pages/Tracker/mysite.tracker.component.ts(10,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module './overlay.service'.
[nodemon] failed to start process, possible issue with exec arguments
events.js:165
      throw err;
      ^

Comment: Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (2)
    at emit (events.js:163:17)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor\run.js:126:11)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)

Comment: I'm more than happy to push the working code to my public site or do a screen share you can see everything in it's entirety.

Comment: that would help, or alternatively you could put together a plunker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129487/discussion-between-mwilson-and-fiddles).

Answer (score 1):

Specifying providers in the Component metadata actually creates a new injectable, scoped to that component tree.

If you want to share the overlay service across the app, you'll need to declare the overlay provider in the NgModule, and not in the components. Alternatively, you can declare it only as a provider on the top-level entry component (eg. AppComponent), though it may cause confusion when used in other entry components/lazy-loaded modules.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html for a better explanation

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading into this now but once I remove `OverlayService` from my component's provider array, I get `Error: Error in http://marcswilson-dev.com/app/../public/app/ts/pages/tracker/mysite.tracker.component.js class TrackerComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for OverlayService!`

Comment: Have you got an NgModule where you've declared providers?

Comment: Hmmm, that's shouldn't be the case. Is OverlayComponent being setup in the MainComponent's template, or the index.html?

Comment: It resides in my MainComponent right now but I just tried moving it into the index.html and no luck.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue